# Laravel Migration: get error when i want to add foreign key

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, database-migration

I'm trying to create foreign keys in Laravel however when I migrate my table using "artisan" I am thrown the following error and i do not know why:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 
Cannot add foreign key 
constraint (SQL: alter table `positions` add constraint 
`positions_car_id_foreign` 
foreign key (`car_id`) references `cars` (`id`))
```

The table car should hava an id which is unique and to every car there are many different positions (lat and long). The car id is the foreign key.

Car migration file:

```
class Car extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cars',function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('id')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('location');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('cars');
}
}
```

Postion migration file:

```
 class Position extends Migration
 {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('positions',function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('car_id')->unsigned();
        $table->double('latitude');
        $table->double('longitude');

    });

    Schema::table('positions',function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('car_id')->references('id')->on('cars');
    });

}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('positions');
}
```

}

Comment: migration files order should be `Car` first then `Position` ??

Comment: The car file gets migrated before the Position file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the foreign key relationship with cars as `$table->integer('car_id')->unsigned()`

So, your migration code for `id` field in `cars` table should be

`$table->unsignedInteger('id')->unique()` instead of `$table->integer('id')->unique()`